# Lookup Columns not showing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a lookup column in a list and want to show a column from another list from the same site, I have completed the following

From ListA I have created a new column using the lookup option, I then select listB to try and find the column but none of the columns I created are showing

[image]

Comment: What were the column types of the fields you created that you are trying to create lookup columns on?

Comment: And in what view are they not visible? They will only be added automatically to the default view with the above setting